# Setting Application.Volatile to False stops cell calculating even when input changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a curious issue where `Application.Volatile False` is preventing my function from being called.

From the MS Help concerning Application.Volatile:

> Marks a user-defined function as volatile. A volatile function must be
> recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the
> worksheet. *A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input
> variables change.* This method has no effect if it's not inside a
> user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell.

My VBA Function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AddOne(d As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile False
    Debug.Print "AddOne called"
    AddOne = d + 1
End Function
```

My *expectation* is that AddOne will only be called if the input `d` changes.

I have a sheet where:

A1 has the formula `=NOW()`

B1 has the formula `=AddOne(A1)`

The Calculation mode is set to Automatic.

**What is surprising me is that B1 does not update with `Shift-F9`** I can see the value in A1 changing, but the value in B1 does not (and nothing appears in the VBA Immediate window).

There is a cryptic comment in the MS Help for `Now()` [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/now-function-3337fd29-145a-4347-b2e6-20c904739c46):

> Note: If the NOW function does not update cell values when you expect
> it to, you might need to change settings that control when the
> workbook or worksheet recalculates. These settings can be changed in
> Control Panel for the Excel desktop application.

But what is the *Control Panel for the Excel desktop application*?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't lose focus. The comment about Now() is irrelevant as you already see A1 value changes.

Second, as you quoted, setting `Application.Volatile False` excludes the function from re-calculation (included F9 or Shift-F9). Thus, the only occasion it does re-calculate is when you select B1 and press Enter.  And during its recalculation, it will check A1's value, which will call NOW(). So, you will also see A1 change.

This is a normal behaviour you are witnessing.